# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 22 declared in library

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I encountered this bug when compiling the ionic project. I have followed the instructions on the Internet to continuously modify the project.properties under `"myproject/platforms/android"` and the project.properties under `"myproject/platforms/android/Coedovalib"`.

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="19"
   android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
```

But this did not take effect. When I cleared android and added android again, the same error still appeared. And, the value I changed was restored.
I saw two articles about "The value of minSdkVersion cannot be changed after it is modified":I have followed the methods they said,but it looks not applied to my cordova lib version.

I want to seek your help to solve the problem which is related the following versions:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 
   19 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.1
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Program Files\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.18.0 (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

By the way, the errors are below:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 22 declared in 
library [:CordovaLib]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two articles I have mentioned above:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/686

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-faild-in-android-uses-sdk-minsdkversion-16-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-19-declared-in-library/132183/10